# Using a link_to with a null field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named hdasset which has a field called Warrantyexpiry. I'm trying to add a link to the index view as below:

`<td><%= link_to hdasset.Warrantyexpiry, hdasset %></td>`

such that a user can click on the Warrantyexpiry field to access the hdasset record. However, this field is sometimes empty. In these cases, I'm seeing a default path like this:
[Warranty Until column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZBMr.png)

Instead, I would like "No Warranty" to show in these cases. Can this be done?

I tried using a helper, but this didn't work.

```
module HdassetsHelper
  def format_warranty(hdasset)
    if Warrantyexpiry.present
      hdasset.Warrantyexpiry
    else
      "No Warranty"
    end
  end
end
```

I'm very new to Rails, so apologies if I'm asking a really stupid question...

Comment: <td><% if Warrantyexpiry.present? %> <%= link_to hdasset.Warrantyexpiry, hdasset %><% else %> "No Warranty" <% end %></td>

Answer (score 0):

There's [a great helper called `link_to_if` for this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) where you can provide a block that becomes the `else`:

```
<%=
  link_to_if hdasset.Warrantyexpiry.present?, hdasset.Warrantyexpiry, hdasset do
    "No Warranty"
  end
%>
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks smathy!